# Facebook developement locally

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

I'm developing a UI functionality for our facebook app locally.

I am getting the content like $auth_url and then adding it in the source `src` of an iframe. But this gives me a few errors like `500 internal server error` and `Permission denied for <http://static.ak.facebook.com> to get property Window.Arbiter` although i do see a facebook.com in the iframe. it works and reloads to the canvas if i use `top.location.href` instead on the same link.

Am I doing something wrong? or am I not allowed to do this locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook will crawl every address it receives a call from, and will subsequently deny requests it cannot perform this crawl for.

Set up port forwarding in your router/modem and patch port 80 through to the web.
Make sure to look up what your external Ip address is, and to update the settings for your app on developers.facebook.com to reflect the external address and path.

be sure to read [this article on local facebook app development](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2007/07/16/how-to-local-facebook-app-development/)

Comment: i read that article and it says to create a local version of the facebook app, i can not do this because it is a company app. will the port forwarding remove the "permission denied" problem?

Comment: It should.
Facebook will only reply to requests from an address it can crawl, so either your company must set up the app on a development server that can be reached from the internet, or you must set up port forwarding from your development machine to the internet.

Comment: It seems to me like an odd requirement to force a calling application to be accessible on the web and crawlable.  Do you know why Facebook requires that?  I read the link, but it didn't explain why.

Comment: An educated guess on my part is as far as i get ; they want to verify that the caller of their api is indeed the registered application with some degree of certainty.
Forcing the calling page to be available, verifiable and identical to the one registered with them is a fairly safe way of doing so.